# Calling ImageMagick from php yields "UnableToOpenModuleFile"

Tags: php, imagemagick

I have a php script that worked for more than a year without any problem. It issues a ImageMagick conversion like this:

```
$cmd = "convert 'src.jpg' -resize 200x150 -quality 90 'dst.jpg'";

exec( $cmd . " 2>&1", $output);
var_dump( $output);
```

But after a System update, I get the following Error

```
array(3) { 
[0]=> string(150) "convert: UnableToOpenModuleFile '/var/services/web/.config/ImageMagick/jpeg.la': No such file or directory @ warning/module.c/GetMagickModulePath/823."
[1]=> string(86) "convert: NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat `JPEG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/572." 
[2]=> string(78) "convert: NoImagesDefined `dst.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3322." }
```

It looks like ImageMagick is malconfigured. But when I issue the identical command from the commandline in a terminal window it works fine.

Php Version is 7.4
ImageMagick Version is 7.0.11-5
Server is Synology with DSM 6.2.3 and Webstation

Any Ideas?

Comment: PHP may be linked to a different version of ImageMagick. With ImageMagick 7, use magick not convert.

Comment: To my understanding, excec calls the externalI imageMagick Convert-Program, just like a call from the commandline. Where is there a link between php and ImageMagick, that has to be maintained?

Comment: My mistake. But as you are on ImageMagick 7, the proper command would be "magick", not "convert". Does that help?  What do you get from `type -a convert` or `type -a magick`?  Do you get more than one version of ImageMagick?  What do you get from `convert -version` or `magick -version`? Do you get different versions?

Comment: Whenn I issue the command directly from the console it works.

Comment: Same error with "magick" instead of "convert".

Comment: Check the versions with and without exec()